# Current transformer (CT)

Tags: current-transformer, toroidal

[image]I want to make a current transformer with specified of 300/5 (I do not want to buy). The tools I have are Silica sheet, Magnet wire‎ and LCR meter. According to this formula "L = NΦ/I" I only know the current, How can I get other parameters? (N and Φ).

Also, what is the formula for toroidal core?

Comment: Looks like a variation of IL=NAB. N is the number of turns. A is the cross section area in square meters. B is your flux in Tesla. L is determined by the Al value of your core according to L = Al x N^2. Or just measure L.